# Qt + QSortFilterProxyModel + QStandardItemModel + QTreeView + crush when remove rows

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a problem when using QTreeView with QStandardItemModel and QSortFilterProxyModel.
My program crushes when I trying remove rows from source model.
In this place

```
parent->removeRow(item->row());
```

[The hole project (tar.gz)](http://yadi.sk/d/uZk-Kfc025UUP)

[pasbin.com](http://pastebin.com/1XJkawan)

stack look like this

```
0       ??      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 0
1       ??      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 0
2       QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 
3       QAbstractItemModel::rowsRemoved(QModelIndex const&, int, int)   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 
4       QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows()     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
5       Widget::remove_items    widget.cpp
6       Widget::Widget          widget.cpp
7       main                    main.cpp
```

I'm using kubuntu 12.10 with Qt 4.8.3.

Have I mistake in my code or it Qt's bug?

Thanks.

---

I tried to build project with 4.8.4 and it works. So I think, that it Qt's bug

Comment: Hard to tell without more context. Are parent and item valid pointers? How does the method look like where you call removeRow()? Run it in a debugger on look at the backtrace.

Comment: Also try to just delete the item instead of removing it first.

Comment: Yes parent and item is valid pointers. Also I check that they belong to the model.

Comment: if(item_index.isValid() && (parent->model() == model_) && (item->model() == model_)
{
    removeRow()
}

Comment: Also I tried to delete items - delete parent->takeChild(item->row()). But after this in QTreeView stay empty nodes in place where items was.

Comment: I meant "delete item;" if all you want to do is remove item

Comment: When I delete the item, it has not removed from source model.
I think so, because empty rows are remained in QTreeView.